# Convert ES6 to ES2015 using babel and laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, babeljs, laravel-mix

I have ES6 JavaScript code in my Vue components. In order to support IE 11 I need to convert it to ES5 code using babel and laravel-mix. How do I do that?

Here is my webpack.mix.js file.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.js('resources/assets/js/admin-app.js', 'public/js')
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a `mix.babel()` command that can handle this.

It's identical to `mix.scripts()` so it requires a little more legwork. I cheat and do this and then serve the es5.js to IE:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .babel('public/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.es5.js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: I'm getting "mix.combine() requires a full output file path as the second argument.", when trying with "mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/admin-app.js', 'public/js')
    .babel('resources/assets/js/spa.js', 'public/js')"

Comment: You need to specify the output file. I have a js file name `app.es5.js` in my babel line.

Comment: Would something like this work? "mix..js('resources/assets/js/spa.js', 'public/js/spa.js')
    .babel('public/js/spa.js', 'public/js/spa.js')"

Answer (score 6):

The code is not 100% correct, babel first argument can be an array, if we want to pass multiple files:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
     .babel(['public/js/app.js'], 'public/js/app.es5.js')
     .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer to maintain `app.js` as my final js output. It's a preferred naming convention.
So like every other person, if babel works for you, then

webpack.confog.js

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app1.js')
  .babel('public/js/app1.js', 'public/js/app.js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

With this I still maintain `public/js` and entry point through out my application.

But I prefer using the solution I posted here:
[Laravel Mix: Configure Babel for IE11 compatibility (transformations and polyfills)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670577/laravel-mix-configure-babel-for-ie11-compatibility-transformations-and-polyfil/62899566#62899566)