# Running 'npm run prod' causes "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, babeljs, laravel-mix

I am trying to enable support for IE 11 using babel polyfills. However, after running `npm run prod`, the file generated produces the following error in the browser:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

This is the very beginning of the `app.es5.js`, hence the `require`:

```
"use strict";var _regenerator=_interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/regenerator"));
```

Looking a [this stackoverflow anser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352701/convert-es6-to-es2015-using-babel-and-laravel-mix/52352875#52352875), my *webpack.mix.js* seems pretty accurate. This is my *webpack.mix.js*:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract()
    .babel(['public/js/app.js', 'public/js/vendor.js'], 'public/js/app.es5.js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/pdf.scss', 'public/css')
    .version();
```

Here is my *.babelrc*:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["IE 11, last 2 versions"]
      }
    }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was CKEditor that was causing this. Commenting out this line: `import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";` solved it.

You can read more about [the CKEditor build process here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html).