# Vue components does not appear on IE11 (Laravel)

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, laravel-mix

All my vue components cannot be rendered in IE11. After searching, it looks like the reason is that IE does not support ES6 and above.

So my attempt at the moment is use babel:

My .**babelrc**:

```
{
"presets": [
    [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            "debug": true,
            "modules": false,
            "forceAllTransforms": true,
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "targets": "last 1 version, > 1%",
            "corejs": 3
        }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And I am using laravel-mix to compile the asset:

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix")

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js/app.js")
.sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css/app.css")
.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
```

The compilation was running ok, but my vue components are still not rendered.

Any pointers to solve the problem?

Thanks.

// **SOLUTION**: [Convert ES6 to ES2015 using babel and laravel-mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352701/convert-es6-to-es2015-using-babel-and-laravel-mix)

Comment: Seen this? [Compiling ES6 and VUE JS not working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52881807/compiling-es6-and-vue-js-not-working-in-ie-11)

Comment: Seen that already. I target IE already: "targets": "last 1 version, > 1%",

Comment: Are you using Babel 6 or 7?

Comment: Babel 7

...15 chars...

Comment: The accepted answer on that linked post shows a Babel 7 solution using `"targets": { "ie": "11" }` with the `@vue/app` preset

Comment: @vue/app preset is for Vue CLI. I'm using Laravel Mix though. 
It looks like they are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Install `babel polyfill`

```sh
npm install --save @babel/polyfill or yarn add @babel/polyfill
```

2. Add the code import `@babel/polyfill` to `src/main.js`.

```
import '@babel/polyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'
// ...
```

3. Change the babel.config.js as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@vue/app',
      {
        'useBuiltIns': 'entry'
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

4. Create the vue.config.js file and create:
   (Add existing settings if they already exist.)

```
const ansiRegex = require('ansi-regex')

module.exports = {
    ......(기존 설정이 있다면 다음에 추가)
    transpileDependencies: [ansiRegex]
}
```

Note. Use `es6-promise` when using a promise pattern.

Comment: How's ansiRegex related to polyfill? Basically your solution is the same as mine.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'ansi-regex' is either. However, this option is used to convert dependencies to an explicit enemy by using Babel. 'ansi-regex' is a regular expression for matching `ANSI escape codes`. See this in relation to the `ANSI escape code`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

I hope it helps.

Comment: Where's the source of this solution? Or does it work for you?